# Filtering out script tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, security

When importing a CSV file, a malicious user could potentially include `<script>` tags and run arbitrary JavaScript. I have this line of code to filter them out (that is, turn them into innocuous `div` tags):

```
data = data.gsub(/<\s*script[^>]*>/i, '<div style="display:none">').gsub(/<\s*\/+script[^>]*>/i, '</div>')
```

Is there a way to defeat this filtering?

Comment: Removing the script tags doesn't solve the underlying problem of preventing XSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a real parser if you want to mess with tags.

It's easy to munge the `<script>` tags into something else:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
  <html>
  <head>
    <script></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>alert('pop this!')</script>
  </body>
  </html>
EOT

doc.search('script').each do |script|
  script.replace("<div>#{ script.content }</div>")
end

puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >> <head>
# >> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
# >> <div></div>
# >> </head>
# >> <body>
# >>     <div>alert('pop this!')</div>
# >> </body>
# >> </html>
```

That grabs the content of the `<script>` tag and inserts it inside a `<div>` tag, then uses that to replace the `<script>` tag.

Alternately, you could just change the name of the `<script>` tag:

```
doc.search('script').each do |script|
  script.name = "div"
end

puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >> <head>
# >> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
# >> <div></div>
# >> </head>
# >> <body>
# >>     <div>alert('pop this!')</div>
# >> </body>
# >> </html>
```

Comment: That needs to be pointed out to the OP, who wants to change the tags, not to me who only answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are many other ways to get an XSS payload into a string, eg, this will work in most browsers (yes, even though there's already another `body` tag).

```
<body onload="alert('foo');">
```

You should HTML encode all input, and use another engine like Markdown if you want to provide formatting options.